# R. Creating a row from column based on specific conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set similar to this one:

```
name     tag
Jane    [nice:5/7], [not funny:4/4], [strange:5/7], [smart:7/7]
Jack    [old:10/10], [very cute:4/6]
Tom     [awesome:2/4]
```

I would like to turn it into the data set that looks like this:

```
name     tag        number1      number2
Jane    nice        5             7
Jane    not funny   4             4
Jane    strange     5             7
Jane    smart       7             7
Jack    old         10            10
Jack    very cute   4             6
Tom     awesome     2             4
```

How should I approach it? Maybe there are some nice packages that could help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `separate_rows` and `extract` from `tidyr`:

*Edit*: Now with two word tags.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  separate_rows(tag, sep = ", ") %>%
  extract(tag, into = c("tag","number1", "number2"),
          regex = "\\[(.+):([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\\]")
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  name  tag       number1 number2
  <fct> <chr>     <chr>   <chr>  
1 Jane  nice      5       7      
2 Jane  not funny 4       4      
3 Jane  strange   5       7      
4 Jane  smart     7       7      
5 Jack  old       10      10     
6 Jack  very cute 4       6      
7 Tom   awesome   2       4
```

Comment: Thank you! It is really helpful. I found an occurring problem with tags that consist of two words, I guess the problem is the space between them. I did not mention them in the question, some tags look like "very nice". How could I specify that sometimes there is a space in the tag?

Comment: You could try replacing `\\w` with `.`.

Comment: Hm. That just creates NAs. I guess, it is easier to remove spaces then

Comment: If you [edit] your question with some examples, I can try to help with a regex pattern.

Comment: Added a couple of examples

Comment: The change to `.` seems to work for me. Make sure you don't miss the `+`.